# Complex Json Data and NSMutableDictionary parsing issue

Tags: iphone, json, parsing, nsmutabledictionary, sbjson

Hi I'm using SBJson for moving Json data in and out of NSMutableDictionar, Im Building the main NSMutableDictionary from few others NSMutableDictionary like this

```
- (NSMutableDictionary *) getGeneral{
    NSMutableDictionary *pType = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [pType setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:3] forKey:@"Ptype"];

    NSMutableDictionary *session = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [session setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:-1] forKey:@"user_id"];
    [session setObject:@"3" forKey:@"device_token"];
    [session setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:-1] forKey:@"customer_id"];
    [session setObject:@"3" forKey:@"client_time"];

    NSMutableDictionary *Error = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [Error setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:-1] forKey:@"error_code"];
    [Error setObject:@"3" forKey:@"error_message"];

    NSMutableDictionary *Successful = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [Successful setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:-1] forKey:@"success_code"];
    [Successful setObject:@"3" forKey:@"success_message"];

    NSMutableDictionary *Details = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [Details setObject:@"3" forKey:@"user_name" ];
    [Details setObject:@"3" forKey:@"user_password" ];
    [Details setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:-1] forKey:@"StartCallID"];
    [Details setObject:@"3" forKey:@"StartDate" ];
    [Details setObject:@"3" forKey:@"EndDate"];

    NSMutableDictionary *General = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];  
    [General setObject:pType forKey:@"Ptype"];
    [General setObject:session forKey:@"Session"];
    [General setObject:Error forKey:@"Error"];
    [General setObject:Successful forKey:@"Successful"];
    [General setObject:Details forKey:@"Details"];
    return General;
}
```

and then i assign data into it i expected to get this Json structure:

```
{
"Ptype":[{"Ptype":-1}],
"Session":[{
"user_id":-1, 
   "device_token":" ", 
"customer_id":-1,  
 "client_time":"",    
}],
"Error":[{"error_code":-1,
"error_message":""}],
"Successful":[{"success_code":-1,
"success_message":""}],
"Details":[{
"user_name":" ",    
"user_password":" ",  
"StartCallID":-1,   
 "StartDate":" ",  
  "EndDate":" "      
}]}
```

but there is no "]" or "[" in my json it looks like this, the order also change but this is not a problem, i take care of it on the server, issue is no square brackets

```
    {"Session":
{"customer_id":-1,
"client_time":"3",
"user_id":-1,
"device_token":"3"},
"Error":{"error_code":-1,"error_message":"3"},
"Successful":{"success_code":-1,"success_message":"3"},
"Details":{"StartCallID":-1,
"user_password":"gg",
"user_name":"ff",
"StartDate":"3",
"EndDate":"3"},
"Ptype":{"Ptype":3}}
```

any one know on this issue, i need multiple items with the same name and this is the json standart for it

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Square brackets surrounds an array and you only have dictionaries.
The key is unique within each dictionary.

For example to put customer_id in a dictionary within an array:

```
    NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                        [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         @"-1",
                         @"customer_id",
                         nil] nil];
```

Link of interest [Understand JSON 3min lesson](http://secretgeek.net/json_3mins.asp)

Comment: Thank Fredrik, you Solved my problem  Shimon Wiener